# Is there any reason to use nodes with zero values?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

When I'm looking at shaders of some authors, I see nodes like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

and I can't understand - why? As I can see, these nodes don't do anything. I've tried to see the difference with/without it and there is no difference at all. Is there any secrets behind it or it's just some legacy author decided to keep? I thought maybe it's for runtime animation, but there's no variables connected to factors or values. Am I miss something?

I can't attach blend file, because this one shader is too big, and I'm not sure if I can share it at all, so, please, take this question as abstract situation.

Comment: The values with 'Clamp' will make sure the output value is inbetween 0 and 1. But my guess is that they are additional nodes with not that big of a purpose, try to change their value and see what it does instead of just enabling/disabling them

Comment: @Alex yes, in this case there is difference, but still can't see any sence of it, since there is no connected values to drivers or timeline. Do you think it could be undeleted legacy when you're trying just to adjust values?

Comment: Yes that's most likely the case

Comment: As @Alex said, one reason could be using them to clamp values. Without knowing what is plugged in there it's hard to tell. Maybe the input values can be outside the 0 to 1 range, then clamping could be a purpose. Or they are there as a kind of default settings, changing nothing, but are there to make it possible to tweak settings (and to first of all give an idea where to tweak settings). But that's just guesswork without knowing the intentions of the author or which effect changing the values will have.